# Joomla 3.2.3 Guest Sessions Ballooning my Database

Tags: session, joomla

Has anyone found a reasonable solution for keeping the _session table in J3 from getting too big? I've tried changing the handler from Database to None... and didn't have an affect. When I tried changing from None to Memcache... it crashed my website. The temporary solution so far, is writing a cron that empties the session table every 30 minutes. But this doesn't seem like a real solution to the problem.

Why does that table fill up so fast? And how can I slow it down?

My site is on a shared server.

Comment: It would seem that your site has a lot of activity and your host does not provide decent enough servers or the other sites on the shared server are also high in activity.

Answer (score 0):

The more visitors, the more resources a website needs. There are plugins that can clean up your sessions tables every x time, Akeeba Admin Tools Pro and NoNumbers Cache Cleaner I think provide this... But if your website has a lot of traffic, you might have to find a better or bigger host.